# what happens to code/data when waiting for an alarm

Tags: android

When an app sets a  repeating alarm and from the users point of view the phone is in normal mode with an alarm in the notification bar what is happening with the code of the app?  I assume the values of all the variables are stored in the phone memory in such a way that when the alarm wakes up the original state is restored.   Does setting an alarm impose much more demand on the battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When an app sets a repeating alarm and from the users point of view the phone is in normal mode with an alarm in the notification bar what is happening with the code of the app?

`AlarmManager` has nothing to do with the AlarmClock application. There is no "alarm in the notification bar" unless you put something there yourself, which would be a bit unusual for an app employing `AlarmManager`.

Assuming you are referring to `AlarmManager`, "what is happening with the code of the app" is it better be shut down. The point behind `AlarmManager` is so you do not have to keep any code in memory just to watch the clock tick by.

> I assume the values of all the variables are stored in the phone memory in such a way that when the alarm wakes up the original state is restored.

That is absolutely incorrect. `AlarmManager` does nothing of the sort. And, a well-written app using `AlarmManager` will get the heck out of memory when it is not delivering any immediate value. If you need data to persist between alarms, use databases or files.

> Does setting an alarm impose much more demand on the battery?

A `_WAKEUP` alarm will have an impact on the battery proportional to the frequency with which the alarm goes off. If the alarm is nice and infrequent (e.g., user configured to every 15 minutes), the alarm itself will have little impact, but what you do when the alarm goes off might.

Comment: Thanks for your response Commons - I have been having problems responding.   I am referring to Alarm Manager and I have learned a lot from your answer to this question.   I have seen conversations here discussing whether it is better to cloase an app or let the system do that itself in due course.    cont....

Comment: In my case tha alrm is set to repeat every 24 hours.  I have found that an arry in the class that both sets the alarm and contains the4 Broadcast Receiver still seems to hold it's values when the alarm wakes up so the r4eason for my original question was to try to understand where this was being maintained and if it was just a matter o luck that it hadn't been overwritten.   I appreciate the pointy about preserving any needed data ijn a file or database.  Thanks for any further help you can offer.